# Simple query regarding simplicial map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Let $f:K\to L$ be a simplicial map.
Let $\sigma=[v_0,v_1,\dots, v_n]$ be a simplex in $K$. By definition of simplicial map, $f(\sigma)$ is a simplex in $L$.

My question is, does $f(\sigma)$ have to be equal to $[f(v_0),f(v_1),\dots,f(v_n)]$? Or can it be something else?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $L$ is a simplicial complex to see that each face $d^i(f(\sigma))$ of $f(\sigma)$ is simplex of $L$. Then use the fact that $f$ is a simplicial map to see that each such face is of the form $f(d^i\sigma)$. Finally use induction to get the answer.

Note that many authors define a simplicial map to be a map of the vertices. Note also that the vertices $f(v_0),\dots,f(v_n)$ are not necessarily distinct.

Comment: Thanks. How do we "use the fact that $f$ is a simplicial map to see that each such face is of the form $f(d^i\sigma)$"?

Comment: This is the definition of a simplicial map: it commutes with the face and coface operators. If you're still unsure, maybe you could give a reference for your definitions and I could be a little more explicit.

Comment: I see.. My main reference is http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimplicialMap.html. So it is true that if $\sigma=[v_0,\dots,v_n]$, $f(\sigma)$ is the simplex spanned by $f(v_0),\dots,f(v_n)$ (not necessarily distinct) right? Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly what the definition that Wolfram gives says (taken vertabim from Munkres). It defines a simplicial map as the extension of a set function $f:K^{(0)}\rightarrow L^{(0)}$ to the whole of the simplicial complex, defined by requiring that it preserve the simplicial relations. I would very much suggest following a textbook if you want to seriously learn the subject. For learning about simplicial complexes I would recommend "Simplicial Structures in Topology" by Ferrario, Piccinini.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation